# How to assign different value to dynamic listboxes?

Tags: python, tkinter

Here is the code in my class that will generate new Listboxes and allow them to be controlled simultaneously

```
for i in range(5):
            self.lb = tk.Listbox(self.modeSelect)
            self.lb.configure(background='#2f2a2d', exportselection='false', font='{Arial} 12 {}', foreground='#feffff', height='23')
            self.lb.configure(relief='flat', width='12')
            self.lb.pack(side='left')
            for j in range(10):
                self.lb.insert("end", f"{i+1},{j+1}")
            self.lb.bind("<Double-1>", self.getIndexLB)
```

I can insert or delete the same value across all 5 listboxes using this function

```
    def addSeq(self, event=None):
        yUser = yInput.get().strip()
        xUser = xInput.get().strip()
        repeatInt = repeatInpu.get().strip()
##      interval_Input = iInput.get().strip()
        clickAmount = int(repeatInt)
        for child in self.modeSelect.winfo_children():
            if isinstance(child, tk.Listbox):
                print(child)
                child.insert(END, yUser)
##                if child.get('end') == yUser:
##                    child.insert(END, 'test')
```

My question is, if I want to input different values in each of the 5 listboxes, how can I do that?

Here is the result of `print(child)`

```
.!labelframe.!listbox
.!labelframe.!listbox2
.!labelframe.!listbox3
.!labelframe.!listbox4
.!labelframe.!listbox5
```

I've tried to use `....!labelframe.!listbox.insert(END, 'value')` but it keeps printing the initial child value across all 5, I've also tried to use an if statement to try and `continue` if the initial child has the same value as my the variable I want to put in, but had no luck.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Assigning all of the listboxes to `self.lb` was pointless, as you're just overwriting the previous one each time.  You should instead append them to a list, so you can simply index into that list to refer to any particular listbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, if I want to input different values in each of the 5 listboxes, how can I do that?

The simplest solution would be to save the listboxes to a list or dictionary so that you can directly reference them.

```
self.listboxes = []
for i in range(5):
    lb = tk.Listbox(self.modeSelect)
    self.listboxes.append(lb)
    ...
...
self.listboxes[0].insert("end", "this is a new value for listbox 0")
self.listboxes[1].insert("end", "hello, listbox 1")
```

Comment: Legend. @Bryan Oakley